# Weird intermittent keymapping issue on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, keyboard

I've got the strangest issue lately. Multiple times a day, one key is duplicating another i.e. a short while ago pressing L was producing E (as well as E still producing E).

I get the same behaviour when using my bluetooth mechanical keyboard (using ZMK firmwars) as well as on my built-in laptop keyboard which makes me think it's a Windows driver issue. I am on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045) on an HP EliteBook 830 G5.

The first time I noticed it, it was producing really weird symbols but I eventually figured out that I had accidentally activated a Dyalog APL keyboard driver that I had installed last year some time. I uninstalled that Dyalog driver so now I don't get the symbols anymore but I get the occasional duplicate key mapping behaviour described above. I've tried changing my input language from US to UK and back again, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

The behaviour only lasts a minute or two at a time until it functions normally again. I haven't been able to figure out if there is something that reliably triggers normal function again. I usually go to the Windows Regional & Keyboard Settings and that seems to fix it but that could also just be time passing. ‍♂️

Any ideas what I can do about this?

Comment: And if you reinstall and then uninstall it?

Comment: Dyalog you mean? That had occurred to me but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Try it. If it works it is probably the easiest fix. Diagnosing problems like this will be difficult.